# Is there a way to tell the AH not to take Gems into account when searching?

Tags: diablo-iii

It drives me crazy that Auction House search results include gems. For example, if I am looking for a hat with 10+ Magic Find on it and at least 1 socket, I get a ton of results for socketted helmets with no magic find, but that are socketed with a Topaz

Is there a way to tell the AH not to include gems attributes when searching for an item?

Comment: I hope there is as the current saturation of the AH makes the interface they apparently have given us very unsatisfactory for finding what it is you are looking for.

Comment: If you're just going to socket it with a topaz, why not just search for hats with +20-30% MF?  I don't see how that would be any different.  If you also want other stats, add them in as criteria.

Comment: @NickT Not every MF hat has a Topaz in it, and this is a problem I see when searching for other items as well, such as wanting gear with specific stats and having results show up only because they are socketed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 1.0.4, [searches do not take into account gems when searching](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6368188147#2), so you don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: NO.

For now the search in auction house is still unsatisfactory.

Search could be better, there is no way to search for DPS on weapons.

Some searches generate no results bug when you switch the order of buyout for example.

Lets hope they fix the bugs and improve the AH asap.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt do that anymore it seems.