# How to exclude Gem bonuses from AH searches?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to tell the AH not to take Gems into account when searching?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68900/is-there-a-way-to-tell-the-ah-not-to-take-gems-into-account-when-searching)

If I search for a chest armor with a socket having 100 dexterity, I often get armors with 50 base dexterity having emeralds. This is not was I am looking for. I want to get an armor with 100+ base armor that I can equip with my emeralds, so I can push it to 150 or more.

Is it possible to exclude gem effects from the results for my query?

Because both alternatives are not really good:

- I can search for the end result (e.g. 150 dex), but I will also get really expensive Armor that has 150 base dex without gems.
- I can search for the real value I want (e.g. 100 dex), but I will get really crappy armor that has these stats only because of gems.

Sure I can narrow my search by the price, but sometimes the gems are really weak and I would need to remove them. This makes the item way more expensive and thus not comparable.