# Gem slot search Auction house

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to tell the AH not to take Gems into account when searching?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68900/is-there-a-way-to-tell-the-ah-not-to-take-gems-into-account-when-searching)

Well here is my problem :

I'd like to find a helm with 20% base MF and a gem slot so i can  reach more than 40%MF. However when i try to search MF20% and gem slot in the auction house i only find helm with like 6-8% base and the bonus from the gem. Does anyone have a tips to hepl me get better result ?

thanks a lot =D

Comment: well thanks, it was not proposed so i thought i was the first to ask

Comment: Search is your friend!  Even when it doesn't work very well.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately it is not possible at this time to exclude items with gems already having magic find from gems in them.

Also i'm fairly sure this got asked a couple of days ago

Comment: It's not possible even if the item doesn't have magic find.  The AH will account for it regardless.

Comment: You can search for helmets with magic find in the just fine you just can'd exclude items that has the magic find from a gem in them.

Comment: If you search for magic find, you will find items that don't have it, but gain it from the gem.  Your wording "already having magic find" implies it will only find items that already have magic find as part of the base item.

Comment: I don't know how to put it then. edit it for me? ofc I mean the same as you. you will find items with no base magic find with a topaz in it, giving magic find